# How to get rid of a table border in wordpress?

Tags: html, wordpress, html-table

I'm building a simple website for a friend of mine using wordpress. In a page I now want to make a simple rectangle and put some info in it. Since I learned html back in the 90's I still use a table (with one td) to do this. Since I want the table border to disappear I created the table like so:

```
<table border="0">
<tr><td>some content</td></tr>
</table>
```

Unfortunately, the border still appears (see [here for the page](http://merkentent.nl/pakketten/) I work on).

Does anybody know how I can get rid of this table border?

Answer (score 5):

You are having this rule in your stylesheet `style.css Line 1071` which needs to be removed

```
th, td, table {
    border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
}
```

Note: This is an element selector, will apply to all the tables in your website.

You've that table inside a div with class `post-entry` so better you can override the styles using the below selector

```
.post-entry *  { /* '*' will select all element inside .post-entry so be cautious */
   border: 0 !important;
}
```

And if you are having `post-entry` for other elements too, explicitly specify the elements instead of using `*`

```
.post-entry table, .post-entry th, .post-entry td {
   border: 0;
}
```

Tip : Use firebug, will save you from asking less questions and wasting less time in debugging your CSS, HTML and JS

Comment: Thanks for that! That totally works. But now all tables on my page have no border. Isn't it possible to make a class or something that I can include in the table so that only that table has no borders?

Comment: @kramer65 Read my answer carefully, you must have used 1st selector, use the last one in my answer and see